Is there a syntactic "higher-up" to derivations?
The question is likely to be illposed, but I was wondering whether there was some known syntactic "higher-up" to the notion of derivation of semi-exoteric use. By this I mean: when working in $\mathsf{PA}$, we make use of digitalization so as to encode finite structures such as: lists, trees, and —on the syntactic side of things— terms, formulæ, derivations.
The main thing to take notice of with regard to these last three is that they make up encodable finite structures in a sort of hierarchical manner of construction (one first has terms, then makes up formulæ through those terms, then constructs derivations with those same formulæ). My question is, then: Is there some next step? Some finitary construction which makes use then of the derivations henceforth constructed?
Perhaps the notion of "metaderivation" could look like such a next step, but it often is rather infinitary (all formulæ of the sort [...] derive [...]), hence breaking the finitary ladder hitherto built.
